# Erro Unity 5 aparentemente codigo

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estava fazendo esse jogo quando apareceu este problema

> Assets/SampleAssets/2D/Scripts/Platformer2DUserControl.cs(2,25): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `CrossPlatformInput' does not exist in the namespace`UnitySampleAssets'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

O meu código esta da seguinte maneira

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnitySampleAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnitySampleAssets._2D
{

    [RequireComponent(typeof (PlatformerCharacter2D))]
    public class Platformer2DUserControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private PlatformerCharacter2D character;
        private bool jump;

        private void Awake()
        {
            character = GetComponent<PlatformerCharacter2D>();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if(!jump)
            // Read the jump input in Update so button presses aren't missed.
            jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
        }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            // Read the inputs.
            bool crouch = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl);
            float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            // Pass all parameters to the character control script.
            character.Move(h, crouch, jump);
            jump = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quando "apareceu" esse problema? O código funcionava e depois deixou de funcionar? Ou o erro está aí desde o início? Esse projeto foi feito do zero ou copiado de algum lugar? Não tenho experiência com o Unity, mas [esse post no unity3d.com](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/755466/the-name-crossplatforminput-does-not-exist-in-the.html) sugere que esse recurso não é nativo do Unity, e sim parte de um projeto ou pacote ("sample assets beta package" eu acho). Seu projeto usa esse pacote? A pasta `CrossPlatformInput` está presente?

Comment: Porque a tag está como `JavaScript` se o código é `C#` ?

Comment: @mgibsonbr é isso mesmo que você falou, esse código deve ser de algum tutorial ou exemplo antigo, pois esse UnitySampleAssests não existe mais tem uns bons 3 anos. Pegar o eixo já é nativo da ferramenta desde então. Aqui tem um exemplo de como pegar comando de eixos, já está no segundo certo.
https://youtu.be/fotMn6x7aoU?t=34m45s

Answer (score 1):

O pacote "UnitySampleAssets" foi disponibilizado no evento Unite em 2014, numa palestra sobre boas práticas para jogos 2D no Unity, você pode baixá-lo [aqui](http://goo.gl/6oSzDx).

Nesse arquivo você vai encontrar esse script que está faltando.

Link da palestra (recomendo): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HM17mAmLd7k

Answer (score 0):

Eu não conheço esse pacote UnitySampleAssets. Você chegou a importa-lo? Será que não deletou alguma pasta dele, por acidente?

Para resolver esse problema, você pode reimportar esse pacote ou deixar de usar o CrossPlatformInput. Comentando a linha `using UnitySampleAssets.CrossPlatformInput;` e trocando todos os `CrossPlatformInputManager` por `Input`.